# What is mean , "consider $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ as the cone over $S^n$ with vertex at the origin"

Tags: calculus, geometry, euclidean-geometry

What is mean , "consider $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ as the cone over $S^n$ with vertex at the origin"  where $S^n$ is the n-sphere in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$

I know that one cone $K\subset \mathbb R^{n}$ is a set such that $\alpha K\subset K$ for all $\alpha\in\mathbb R_{+}$,.

I know that is neccesary consider polar coordinate for understand this in a best way, so i need to find a function $\psi: S^n \to \mathbb R^{n+1}$?

I have trouble with the meaning of this statement consider $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ as the cone over $S^n$ with vertex at the origin

Please, can you give me a hint or what i need to do?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please define, elaborate or explain, what is $S^n$

Comment: Thank you @nickalh, i will that, is the n-sphere

Comment: This looks like an elaborate way to say that you should consider polar coordinates.

Comment: Is confuse for me, what is mean that? what i need to do for understand this, can tell me please?

Comment: oh i see, as a identification , i get it. erhaps you know why some people mention the word Cone? Thank you @coffeemath

Comment: You should give the complete definition of a cone with vertex at the origin.

Comment: @PaulFrost It is likely that such a definition was not provided by the source that confused OP

Comment: Note that in Mosher's answer, the map $\psi$ essentially identifies the polar coordinate parametrisation of $\Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$

Comment: Yes, i do not find that definition, so by the answer of @Mosher it help me now

Comment: The cone in this case is $S^{n-1}\times [0,\infty)$?

Comment: For both the cone and the sphere, does it include the interior or only the surface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that you should consider the function
$$\psi : S^{n-1} \times [0,\infty) \mapsto \mathbb R^n
$$
defined by $f(p,r) = rp$ (i.e. scalar multiplication).

This function maps $S^{n-1} \times 0$ to the origin of $\mathbb R^n$.

Also, for each $p \in S^{n-1}$ this function maps $p \times [0,\infty)$ to the ray in $\mathbb R^n$ that is based at the origin and that passes through $p$.

Comment: thank you so much, maybe you know the definition of cone with vertex at the origin?

Comment: That definition is exactly what I have written in my answer. To emphasize the concept of the vertex of the cone, that is the point where all of the rays $f(p \times [0,\infty))$ come together, and it is the origin of $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: thank you so much